# Unable to find java.lang package for flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I'm beginner for flutter. After coding something I want to simulate codes for Android emulator. I could run successfully a few days ago but today I can't. Error code says unable to find package java.lang. I didn't find where I should look for find problem. SDK path is correct, flutter doctor didn't find any problem. Also I can run project with iOS emulator. I am working on MacOS. Here whole error information.

```
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: try using flutter clean command and then run again using flutter run

Comment: I will try @AR , thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is about packages. Some of them needs android migrate to androidx. When project migrated androidx, problem is solved.

[Documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/androidx-migration)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to run with verbose enabled, `flutter run -v`. Then you can find the possible error and warnings. It also happens when your code is incompatible to the gradle version. And the solution for it is to delete `.gradle` from your use home folder, then on next build flutter will redownload compatible gradle version. In case of Linux, `rm -rf ~/.gradle`.